# Accessing this of outerclass from anonymous inner class where outerclass has a generic

Tags: java, generics, inner-classes

I have some code like this:

```
public class ModelLoader<T extends Model> {
    public ArrayList<T> fromJson(JSONArray jsonObjects) {
         // blah blah blah
    }

    public void getAll(final OnRequestCompleted<T> callback) {
        client.get(endpoint, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray resp) {
                // I want to call the fromJson method here
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I have seen in various places that I can use `OuterClass.this`, which in this case would be `ModelLoader<T>.this` but that gives me syntax error.

How can I do this?

Comment: That works...can you write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ModelLoader.this instead.